# OpenGL additive blending not working as expected

Tags: opengl, blending, fragment-shader

I am trying to achieve additive blending with point sprites.  When the sprites overlap, all I get is solid red, when I expect to get a smooth blend from red->yellow->white.  My sprite texture has all four channels set equal, with portions being white and others transparent.

I set up blending as such:

```
  glEnable(GL_BLEND);
  glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE);
```

My fragment shader is as follows:

```
  vec4 texCol = texture(pointsprite, gl_PointCoord);
  colorOut = vec4(texCol.rgb * vec4(ocolor, 1.0).rgb, texCol.a);
```

Where `pointsprite` is a sampler2D and `ocolor` is `(1.0, 0.0, 0.0)

My background is cleared as

```
  glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
```

I have tried some of the various methods suggested in [this question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/22989/how-can-i-achieve-a-good-fire-effect-with-alpha-blending-and-particles), none offering any results.  I can verify my alpha channel is correctly loaded from my image into my texture.

EDIT: Missed mentioning that my intention is for clusters of point sprites with the same pigment (red) to additive blend to yellow and white.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the results you're currently getting, and clarify what you're trying to achieve?  It's not obvious to me from your description what is the result you actually want.  (BTW, with additive blending, the alpha channel doesn't affect the RGB at all.)

Comment: "*When the sprites overlap, all I get is solid red.*" And... what exactly do you *expect* to get? Because, unless you're rendering to a high-dynamic range framebuffer, additive blending is almost always the *wrong* thing to do. So why do you *want* additive blending?

Comment: @NicolBolas in my situation, additive blending is definitely what I want.  Should I use HDR?

Comment: RED + RED = RED, never yellow.  (1,0,0)red+(1,0,0)red=(2,0,0)very red.  `GL_ONE` doesn't say to _swap the color channels_.  You would need to experiment with [GL_SRC_COLOR](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glBlendFunc.xml) but it will probably be difficult to get the effect you want.  Unfortunately fragment shaders don't make it easy to access previously rendered fragments -- except via framebuffer.

Comment: I'm quite curious why you expect additive blending of red colors to go to yellow and white. I think it would help to see your thought process. Is it because you see white as what you get when you add all color together, and you see yellow as halfway between red and white? You need red, green, and blue added together to end up with white - not just red. Also, yellow is not a lighter red. A lighter red is a pinkish color. Yellow is in fact what you get if you mix red and green light together.

Comment: After seeing particles that we're *mostly* red blend into white, I reasoned that if mostly red particles blended into white, fully red particles must blend even better... This was quite wrong, but I figured that when the red channel "overflowed" so to speak, the final color was simply brightened.  Very, very, very wrong

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can achieve the effect you are looking for by setting the color value to non-pure red. In the picture below I have drawn a circle with additive blending multiple times with small offsets. On the left the color is pure red (255, 0, 0) and on the right it is (255, 20, 5). From these you can calculate that to get full yellow, you need 255/20=13 overlapping circles and to get pure white you need 255/5=51 overlapping circles. When you reach full yellow (green channel goes to 255), there is also 65 (25%) on the blue channel, but that should not be an issue. Adjust the numbers as you feel.

[image: Additive blending]

In your case the color you should change is `ocolor`. If you are not rendering sprites with multiple colors, you could also use white for `ocolor` and draw the different colors in the texture itself. This would give more freedom to define how each pixel on the sprite behaves with additive blending.

Answer (score 5):

> Missed mentioning that my intention is for clusters of point sprites with the same pigment (red) to additive blend to yellow and white.

That right there is indicative of your problem.

You cannot take a color value of (0.25, 0, 0), and add it to itself and get anything besides *more red*. It will not magically become yellow, then white. It will always be red, and it will always have zero green or blue (which are necessary to achieve yellow and white).

[Blending](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Blending) is just math; nothing more, nothing less. Math on colors is no different from math on things that aren't colors.

If you want adding "red" to eventually produce yellow and white, then you're going to need to have some blue and green in there.

Furthermore, you're going to have to use some form of [tone mapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tone_mapping) and [high-dynamic range rendering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-dynamic-range_rendering) to make this work out in a reasonable way.

Comment: I've found it useful to enforce a maximum saturation of 99% or so on colors in the framebuffer.  This can be done quickly using `rgb = max(rgb, luminance * 0.01)` just before applying the tonemapping function.  That way even if an artist creates something that's pure red, we'll force it to have *some* green and blue so it'll tonemap reasonably.

Answer (score 2):

Well, your `glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE)` is likely to blame.

The 1st argument to `glBlendFunc` is *how much of the source* (new pixel) to use.  The 2nd arg is how much of the *destination* (pixel already there in the frame buffer) to use.  You said to just add 100% of the source pixel with 100% of the destination pixel.  That's probably not how you want to blend for translucency though.

Common settings to get translucency are calling `glBlendFunc` with

```
glBlendFunc( GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA ) ;
```

An example of the math that happens is [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/etayrien/alpha-blending-part-1).  That says, ok, say the new pixel had alpha =0.75.  Then the blended color would be 0.75*NEWPIXEL + 0.25*OLDPIXEL.  Which looks like transparency.

[Don't forget to turn off depth mask!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3388294/opengl-question-about-the-usage-of-gldepthmask/3390094#3390094).

Comment: He says he wants additive blending though.  Maybe what he really wants is `glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE)`, i.e. additive but fading out according to source alpha...

Comment: For anyone wanting to read the link to MSDN posted by bobobobo : MS has archived the blog post so the URL is wrong but the article is still there. The new address is https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/etayrien/alpha-blending-part-1 .

Comment: Thanks @Scylardor, also here: http://web.archive.org/web/20150922125039/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/etayrien/archive/2006/12/07/alpha-blending-part-1.aspx?Redirected=true, I edited your link into the post